# Iterating through array within array and storing to variables

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, iteration, orientation

I'm looking for some help with the following code:

```
class Journey

    @@journey_count = 0

    def initialize (reg, driver, destin1, destin2)
        @reg = reg
        @driver = driver
        @destin1 = destin1
        @destin2 = destin2
        @@journey_count += 1
    end

end

class Destination
    def initialize (eta, starttime, endtime, punctuality)
       @eta = eta
        @starttime = starttime
        @endtime = endtime
        @punctuality = punctuality
    end
end

# save text file to string
data = File.read("workdata.txt")

# split string into blocks of text relevant to each journey
journeys = data.split(/\n\s\n/)

# store the amount of journeys as a variable called journeys_size
journeys_size = journeys.length
# puts journeys_size

# split each journey into lines and save to an array called "journey_lines"
@journey_lines = journeys.map { |i| i.split(/\n/) }
```

Now I have an array of arrays. I would like to iterate through each element of my main array (which are also arrays) and store certain lines of the inner arrays into a new object based on my journey class defined above. I know it's incorrect but something like...

```
@journey_lines.each do |line0, line5, line6, line7|
    @@journey_count + =1 = journey.new
    line1 = @reg
    line2 = @driver
    line3 = @destin1
    line4 = @destin2
   end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is what you need to do:

```
all_journey_objects = []
@journey_lines.each do |line|
    #line should be an array
    #line[0] should be pointing to corresponding 'reg'
    #line[5] should be pointing to corresponding 'driver'
    #line[6] should be pointing to corresponding 'destin1'
    #line[7] should be pointing to corresponding 'destin2'
    #since you have already defined initialize method in Journey class, can create an object this way
    journey = Journey.new(line[0] , line[5] , line[6] , line[7])
    all_journey_objects << journey
end
# all_journey_objects will be an array of all the new Journey objects that you have initialized.
```

Let me know if I have misunderstood the question. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way

```
 @all_journeys = @journey_lines.map { |line| Journey.new(line[0],line[5],line[6],line[7]) }
```